# How can i iterate the contents in django template language

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

i have one blog page here im trying to implement if i click the blog title or readmore link it will be redirect and display the detailed contents of the blogs

Model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = RichTextField()
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/blogs')
    posted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self) :
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse("blog_detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        db_table = "core_Blog"

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, Blog)
```

View

```
def BlogView(request):
    blog = Blog.objects.all()
    context ={
        'blog' : blog
    }
    return render(request, 'main/blog.html', context)

def BlogDetail(request,slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.filter(slug = slug)

    if blog.exists():
        blog = Blog.objects.get(slug = slug)
    else:
        return redirect('404')
        
    context = {
        'blog' : blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/blog_detail.html', context)
```

HTML for blog page

```
{% for i in blog %}
                    <div class="col-xl-6" style="height: 500px;">
                        <div class="single-smblog mb-30">
                            <div class="smblog-thum">
                                <div class="blog-image w-img">
                                    <a href="blog-details.html"><img src="{{i.image}}" height="180px" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-tag blog-tag-2">
                                    <a href="blog.html">Food Beverage</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="smblog-content smblog-content-3">
                                <h6><a href="{{i.get_absolute_url}}">{{i.title}}</a></h6>
                                <span class="author mb-10">posted by <a href="#">{{i.posted_by}}</a></span>
                                <p>{{i.content | safe | truncatechars:150}}</p>
                                <div class="smblog-foot pt-15">
                                    <div class="post-readmore">
                                        <a href="{{i.get_absolute_url}}"> Read More <span class="icon"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="post-date">
                                        <a href="blog-details.html">{{i.posted_date}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Blog detail page HTML

so here I'm trying to iterate the blog contents in this HTML page I want to display the entire content stored on the Blog model (fieldname=content).  but it's not working properly

```
<div class="news-detalis-content mb-50">
                    <ul class="blog-meta mb-20">
                       <li><a href="blog-details.html"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i>100 Views</a></li>
                       <li><a href="blog-details.html"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> 30 Comments</a></li>
                       <li><a href="blog-details.html"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> 24th March 2021</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    {% for i in blog.content_set.all %}
                    {{i.content}}
                    {% endfor %}

<div class="news-info d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-50 mb-50">
                       <div class="news-tag">
                         <h6 class="tag-title mb-25">Releted Tags</h6>
                          <a href="#"> Popular</a>
                          <a href="#">Desgin</a>
                          <a href="#">UX</a>
                       </div>
                       <div class="news-share">
                          <h6 class="tag-title mb-25">Social Share</h6>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-typo3"></i></a>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></a>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-share-alt"></i></a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
```

i want to display if i click the blog title or readme option the page will be redirect and show the contentes .. the contents are stored in Blog model for the field name content . so here im trying to iterate the contents but its not working properly

Comment: It is just `blog.content` instead of `blog.content_set.all`.

Comment: Bro I already tried **{% for i in blog.content %}
                        {{i.content}}
                    {% endfor %}**  But not working

Comment: `Content` is an attribute of the `Blog`. Therefore, there is nothing you can iterate on. Check out the [Django queries and ORM documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/) to learn more about Django and its ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Answer to your question

The template for your `BlogDetail`view does not require a loop, because you are just passing one single `Blog`object to it.

So instead of this:

```html
{% for i in blog.content_set.all %}
{{i.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

Go for this:

```html
{{ blog.content }}
```

##### Advice unrelated to question

You can improve the code for the `BlogDetail`view utilizing the [`get_object_or_404`method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def BlogDetail(request,slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.get_object_or_404(slug = slug)
        
    context = {
        'blog' : blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/blog_detail.html', context)
```

This makes sure that your detail view is going to error if the database lookup with the slug delivers more than one or less than one result. This is the logic you are looking for if you want to display content for one single object.